# KDE widget to hold a program

Tags: kde, widgets, hamster

I am using KDE default install on Ubuntu 13.04. Is there a widget that will just hold a running program?

I will then, for instance, be able to run hamster-time-tracker in that widget and quickly access it by going to widget overview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are looking but there is

**Embed window ?**

The KDE svn playground has the old http://websvn.kde.org/trunk/playground/base/plasma/applets/embed-win/

it is source code - seems to work with the Kubuntu 13.04.

It will embed the application as plasmoid.

KDE System Activity embedded to the plasma widget.

[image]

**Q**

> Provided that it could be any application, this is perfect! But I could not figure out > what to do with all those files on the link you have given.

**Build example**

Build is depending:

- build-essential
- cmake
- kdelibs5-dev

Source download:

```
svn co svn://anonsvn.kde.org/home/kde/trunk/playground/base/plasma/applets/embed-win
```

This should download:

```
embed-win/Messages.sh
embed-win/embed-win.cpp
embed-win/CMakeLists.txt
embed-win/embed-win.h
embed-win/plasma-applet-embed-win.desktop
```

Open a konsole to the embed-win directory

Make the build directory

```
mkdir -p builddir
```

Move to the builddir

```
cd builddir
```

Execute the cmake with the command

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`kde4-config --prefix`
```

Should tell:

```
...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: ../embed-win/builddir
```

Execute the make

```
make
```

Should tell:

```
Scanning dependencies of target plasma_applet_embed-win_automoc
Generating embed-win.moc
[  0%] Built target plasma_applet_embed-win_automoc
Scanning dependencies of target plasma_applet_embed-win
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/plasma_applet_embed-win.dir/plasma_applet_embed-win_automoc.o
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/plasma_applet_embed-win.dir/embed-win.o
Linking CXX shared module lib/plasma_applet_embed-win.so
[100%] Built target plasma_applet_embed-win_automoc
```

Install

```
sudo make install
```

Should tell:

```
[  0%] Built target plasma_applet_embed-win_automoc
[100%] Built target plasma_applet_embed-win
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "RelWithDebInfo"
-- Installing: /usr/lib/kde4/plasma_applet_embed-win.so
-- Installing: /usr/share/kde4/services/plasma-applet-embed-win.desktop
```

Uninstalling - remove the /usr/lib/kde4/plasma_applet_embed-win.so and /usr/share/kde4/services/plasma-applet-embed-win.desktop or run the 'sudo make uninstall' in the same directory as you executed the 'sudo make install'.

Comment: Provided that it could be any application, this is perfect! But I could not figure out what to do with all those files on the link you have given. Would be great if you could explain.